# Get first few elements of tuples from list of list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a structure of list of list of tuples like:-

```
[[(1, 1, 96),
  (1, 2, 95),
  (0, 5, 23),
  (0, 6, 22)],
 [(2, 1, 145),
  (1, 2, 144),
  (10, 3, 143),
  (2, 4, 142)]]
```

I basically want to obtain 2 list of list of tuples from this. One tuple for the first 2 columns, and the other tuple for the third column.
Desired output:-

```
[[(1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (0, 5),
  (0, 6)],
 [(2, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (10, 3),
  (2, 4)]]
```

&&

```
[[(96,),
  (95,),
  (23,),
  (22,)],
 [(145,),
  (144,),
  (143,),
  (142,)]]
```

How can this be done in python?

Comment: `(96)` (equivalent to `96`, an integer), or `(96,)` (a 1-tuple)?

Comment: (96,) equivalent to 1-tuple.

Comment: `(96)` is not equivalent to 1-tuple. `(96)` is just an integer in parentheses, equivalent to `(95+1)`. `(96,)` is a 1-tuple. See: `(96) + (1)` is `97`; `(96,) + (1,)` is `(96, 1)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Amadan. I have updated the question and my comment as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Amadan's answer worked fine, I wanted to write a generic function to achieve the desired result. Here is the final code:-

```
def fn(data, one_shot_columns, scalar_columns):
     zipped=list(zip(*data)) 
     one_shot_zipped=[zipped[i] for i in one_shot_columns] 
     one_shot=list(zip(*one_shot_zipped)) 
     scalar_zipped=[zipped[i] for i in scalar_columns] 
     scalar=list(zip(*scalar_zipped)) 
     return (one_shot,scalar)
```

used like:-

```
hist_oneshot,hist_scalar = fn(hist,[0,1],[2])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[[(a, b) for a, b, *c in r] for r in arr]
# => [[(1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 5), (0, 6)], [(2, 1), (1, 2), (10, 3), (2, 4)]]

[[tuple(c) for a, b, *c in r] for r in arr]
# => [[(96,), (95,), (23,), (22,)], [(145,), (144,), (143,), (142,)]]
```

In response to comments:

```
def slice_nested_array(arr, start, stop=None, step=1):
    if stop is None:
        stop = len(arr[0][0])
    return [[tuple(l[start:stop:step]) for l in r] for r in arr]

slice_nested_array(arr, 0, 2)
# => [[(1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 5), (0, 6)], [(2, 1), (1, 2), (10, 3), (2, 4)]]
slice_nested_array(arr, 2)
# => [[(96,), (95,), (23,), (22,)], [(145,), (144,), (143,), (142,)]]
```

Comment: This works great! Also, is there a way to write some sort of generic function, that takes in the column value in the output. Like :- def get_first_x_columns(arr,columns), where here the value of columns would be (0,1).

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you should show an example of how that function would be used.

Comment: Basically, If I add another columns, then the below command in your answer would become:-  [[(c, d) for a, b, c,*d in r] for r in arr]. So, I want it to be configurable, so that each time a new column is added, this can be avoided. As in, in the function I could pass [arr,(0,1)] for the first 2 columns, and [arr,(2,3)] for the next 2.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep it really simple, and loop over the nested list, and take what you need:

```
lst = [[(1, 1, 96),
        (1, 2, 95),
        (0, 5, 23),
        (0, 6, 22)],
       [(2, 1, 145),
        (1, 2, 144),
        (10, 3, 143),
        (2, 4, 142)]]

first = []
second = []

for l in lst:
    for tup in l:
        first.append(tup[:-1])
        second.append((tup[-1],))

print(first)
# [(1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 5), (0, 6), (2, 1), (1, 2), (10, 3), (2, 4)]
print(second)
# [(96,), (95,), (23,), (22,), (145,), (144,), (143,), (142,)]
```

Or with list comprehensions:

```
first = [tup[:-1] for l in lst for tup in l]
second = [(tup[-1],) for l in lst for tup in l]
```

Then turn these lists into 2 sublists each:

```
sublen = len(lst[0])

def split_lists(l, s):
    return [l[i:i+s] for i in range(0, len(l), s)]

print(split_lists(first, sublen))
# [[(1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 5), (0, 6)], [(2, 1), (1, 2), (10, 3), (2, 4)]]

print(split_lists(second, sublen))
# [[(96,), (95,), (23,), (22,)], [(145,), (144,), (143,), (142,)]]
```